# Logical and, comparison with numpy nan with float

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I am not sure why but when I use a logical & comparison with numpy.nan value, the statement gets executed. In this example, the if statement says that if xx and yy is NOT a nan value, execute the if statement. Since xx is a nan value, the if statement shouldnt get executed, but it still does.
I tried the same code using `xx = None` instead, and then it works perfectly fine (doesn't get executed)
Any ideas why this is?

```
xx = np.nan
yy = 20
if (xx != np.nan) & (yy != np.nan):
    print('if statement executed')

Out:
if statement executed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `np.nan != np.nan`.  [There are some good reasons for this behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN), but it's one of the unintuitive things we just have to live with.  Use `np.isnan` instead to check for NaN.

Note that `np.nan is np.nan`, but to use `is` for checking is not advisible in general, because there are actually *multiple* float values that are NaN, which are not the same constant (e.g., some other algorithm might return a value that `isnan`, but `is not np.nan`).

Answer (score 2):

Note that

```
import numpy as np
print(np.nan != np.nan)
```

gives:

```
True
```

You might use `numpy.isnan` function for checking that.